# .ideavimrcが反映されない

Tags: vim

.ideavimrcを作成しましたが、設定が反映されません。

使用ソフトは、CLion 2018.2.4です。
IdeaVimのバージョンは、0.49です。
OSは、Windows 10(64bit)です。

以下の.ideavimrcを作成し、ホームディレクトリに置いて、
`:source ~/.vimrc` や `:source ~/.ideavimrc` を実行したり、CLionを再起動したりしてみましたが、反映されません。

```
noremap s i
```

なお、GVIMを用いると、全く同じ内容の.vimrcの内容はきちんと反映されます。

解決方法をご教授いただけると助かります。よろしくお願いします。